# Google Cloud Functions error - intermittent error - timeout on simple function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

First time poster - fairly new to development so please forgive my ignorance. Any help is appreciated.

I am getting intermittent timeout errors for cloud functions. Couple things to know. These functions are super small, usually only take 150ms or less. Timeout error only happens on cold starts. Timeout error doesn't happen every time, maybe one in 8-10. I know I am supposed to return a promise, let me know if I somehow am not.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is this a normal issue with cloud functions?

Sample Code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.editCustomerHttp = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  let Customer = {
    customerId: data.docId,
    customerName: data.oldCustomerName,
  }

  const batch = db.batch();

  const editCustomerRef = db.collection(data.orgName).doc(data.orgId).collection("Customers").doc(data.docId);
  batch.update (editCustomerRef, {
    customerName: data.newCustomerName,
    customerNameSortBy: data.newCustomerNameSortBy,
  })

  const editDropdownRefOld = db.collection(data.orgName).doc(data.orgId);
  batch.update (editDropdownRefOld, {
    'ListOfCustomers': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(Customer),
  })

  return batch.commit()

  .catch(error => {
    console.error("New Customer Failed to be Edited", error)
  })

})
```

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: This is what I get. "Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'"

Comment: More info - I have gotten the same thing happening regardless of which function I run. I also have rewritten my functions to use Async Await (thank you for your video on it, helped a lot), and I've re-written them all to work as http.onCall functions, where I originally did them as cloud firestore triggers. However, I have written them, I always get this timeout error - once in awhile. With http I can handle the error, but it gets a little tricky when it happens for my createUser function.

Comment: Sorry to inundate you, but a little more info to potentially help. My typical function uses between 60-70mb of memory, and the intermittent timeout happens whether I dedicate  256MB all the way up to 2GB .

Comment: Does your function work? I mean when there is not time out, do you see the Firestore documents being updated?

Comment: Yes, it works 9 out of 10 times perfectly. The only time it seems to fail is on a cold start and even then only about 1/3 to 1/4 of the time. I have tested it repeatedly using the same method each time. Also, it doesn't appear to be a permissions issue as I've tested that as well - as far as I can tell.  It's also not just this function, but all the functions I've written that have the same intermittent time out issue (when in reality, the functions themselves are very quick/simple.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your execution took 60004 ms (60 seconds), before it timed out. By default, a function times out after 1 minute, but can extend this period up to 9 minutes. I recommend you read through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout), as it provides more details on how to handle timeouts in Cloud Functions.

The snippet below includes code that is scheduled to execute 2 minutes after function execution starts. If the timeout happens to be set to 1 minute, this code might never execute:

```
exports.afterTimeout = (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // May not execute if function's timeout is <2 minutes
    console.log('Function running...');
    res.end();
  }, 120000); // 2 minute delay
};
```

A good practice to avoid timeouts for your functions is using a combination of the following techniques:

1. Set a timeout that is higher than your expected function execution time.
2. Track the amount of time left during execution and perform cleanup/exit early.